# How to do manual save on entities?

Tags: breeze

I want to manually save changes to the server, that are made to entities on the client. So my first question is: how do I find these entities (querying)?

After I have saved the entities, I want to tell the breeze-client that these entities are no longer in a pending-save-state. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EntityManager.getChanges](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_getChanges) method allows you to retrieve any changes made to any client side entities.

Calling the [EntityAspect.acceptChanges](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_acceptChanges) method will return any entity to the 'unmodified' state.

However... a much cleaner method of doing both of these things is to simply intercept the SaveChanges call on the server and implement your own logic there.  In this case the Breeze client will handle both of the issues you mention.

See the NoDb example in the Breeze zip for a simple example of this.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to achieve what I wanted, with your help.